# Node.js: recursive require and exports

Tags: node.js, module

Simply: How can I make a `require()` of a `require ()`, and then get data back to original with an `exports` of an `exports`?

Here is a practical example:

My `hello.js` file:

```
var text = "Hello world!"
exports.text
```

In the same folder, I have the `foo.js` file:

```
var hello = require("./hello.js")
exports.hello
```

Finally, my `app.js` file (also in the same folder):

```
var foo = require("./foo.js")
console.log(foo.hello.text)
```

I'm expecting it to return:

```
Hello world!
```

But instead, it returns an error:

```
/Users/Hassinus/www/node/test/app.js:2
console.log(foo.hello.text)
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Hassen/www/node/test/app.js:2:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Any help? This situation is not so tricky: I would like to group my scripts in a folder with a unique entry script, that will call functions in various other files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have to name the exports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont set any values on the exports. You have to do something like `exports.text = text` otherwise the export has no value

hello.js

```
var text = "Hello world!";
exports.text = text;
```

foo.js file:

```
var hello = require("./hello.js");
exports.hello = hello;
```

app.js file

```
var foo = require("./foo.js");
console.log(foo.hello.text);
```